# What is the processed called when converting data in repeated columns to rows on a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, terminology

If I have a spreadsheet with a data structure where similar information is repeated across multiple columns like so:

```
TxID     Date      Merchant   Item 1 Name   Item 1 Value   Item 2 Name   Item 2 Value, etc...
0000001  1/1/2020  Macy's     Jeans         $50.00         Socks         $10.00
```

What is the name of the process that converts the data to have similar data presented in a single column, with information repeated across multiple rows as needed:

```
TxID     Date      Merchant   Item Name     Item Value
0000001  1/1/2020  Macy's     Jeans         $50.00         
0000001  1/1/2020  Macy's     Socks         $10.00
```

Having data in the second format is much easier to process, as it guarantees specific information is in a single column, e.g. to sum all sales for socks, I would only need to check a single Item Name and Item Value columns, rather than searching across multiple columns.

I can't recall what this process is called, which makes it difficult to find resources on how to do it effectively. My first though was this is similar to [database denormalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization), however that requires data to be normalised first, so I don't think that's the correct term. [Transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition) also didn't seem correct, as it seems to refer to rearranging all data from columns to rows, rather than just a subset.

Is there a term for this type of data processing?

Answer (score 0):

Process is called `UNPIVOT`.

[Here](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm05UAxnQKMFm8/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2F5UAxnQKMFm8) is some script for GoogleSheets.

[Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/) is example of using Power Query in MS Excel